# Is There A Different Way To Process Input Other Than "If" Statements?

Tags: c, logic

I am a beginner with C and programming in general (I have been programming with C/C++ for two years now), and the only types of programs I have ever made were command line math processors which take arguments and do operations on them. There is no forking of what is to be done based off of what the input is. I don't know how to do something like that, so what I have been doing recently is designing my programs in a way that is like:

```
printf("What feature to use?");
int response;
scanf("%d", response);
if (response == 1)
{
     feature01();
}
if (response == 2)
{
     feature02();
}
```

... and I continue on like this. For my programs with usually less than 10 unique features, this is OK, but only for the time being. If I ever wrote a program with 50-100 unique branch features, there might be an issue. How can you process input and branch to different features without using the if statement in the fashion above?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: What you need is multiple dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function table.  First, a `typedef`

```
typedef void (*feature)();
```

`feature` now stands for a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns `void`.

Now, write (and notice the index change)

```
void feature0() {...}
void feature1() {...}
// ...
void feature9() {...}
```

And then put these into an array:

```
feature[] actions = {&feature0, &feature1, ..., &feature9};
```

And then your code becomes (error checking left out):

```
printf("What feature to use?");
int response;
scanf("%d", &response);
actions[response]();
```

Pointers to functions get treated as the actual functions when called.

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing this up, this is a great technique.

Comment: You need to edit your call to `scanf` too; I just cut and pasted, and neither your code or my code will work.  You need to pass pointers to the function.  See my edited version above, please.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace a series of `if` statements on mutually-exclusive values with `switch` in many situations:

```
switch (response)
{
    case 1:
        feature01();
        break;
    case 2:
        feature02();
        break;
    default:
        featureXX();
        break;
}
```

That's roughly equivalent to:

```
if (response == 1)
{
    feature01();
}
else if (response == 2)
{
    feature02();
}
else
{
    featureXX();
}
```

...except that the compiler can optimize the `switch` a bit more.

Comment: I never knew how to use the "case" tool. Thank you for answering my question.